# How do filters work in image processing?

Tags: image-processing

I have a sobel edge detector example that uses this algorithm

[image]
[image]

So basically it goes through every pixel and alters its value using the impulse function, b. The filters it uses in the impulse function are:

```
{{-1, 0, 1},  {{-1,-2,-1},
 {-2, 0, 2},   { 0, 0, 0},
 {-1, 0, 1}}   { 1, 2, 1}}
```

But why does it use negative numbers on one end of the filter and positive numbers on the other end? I understand using 2 the closer you are to the origin but I don't understand what purpose the negative numbers serve.

Comment: The negative numbers are there so that the filter sums to zero. Otherwise you'll effectively add a constant to the image.

Comment: when it says "the impulse function also exists in a 2D spati..... is it summing each coordinate individually or the matrix as a whole?

Comment: The filter is convolved with the image.  In other words, the operation steps through each pixel of the image and applies the filter to the surrounding region (in your specific case, a 3x3 area).  The result is the sum of the pixel values in the surrounding region multiplied by the weights in the filter. The "2D spatial domain" of the impulse filter is the "neighborhood" of surrounding pixels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sobel filter aims at computing the **gradient** of an image. It means it has to compute local **differences** between pixels. That’s way you have negative coefficients: to obtain differences.
Further, the edges are detected as regions with a high absolute value of the gradient.

Comment: I am getting closer to understanding. I just noticed the original pixel has no say in what the result pixel will be. The result pixel is calculated purely from the gradient. But it says the impulse function is 1 where x and y are zero and zero everywhere else. which i would think means that only the exact pixel would be used to get the result pixel and clearly that isn't right.

Comment: You’re right: the current pixel has no influence when computing its’ gradient. In fact it would be more precisely to compute the difference between neighbor pixels (P(i+1)-P(i) instead of P(i+1)-P(i-1)), but this will give the value of the gradient between two pixels (G(i+0.5)), which can not be properly stored (unless you shift it by 0.5px). Therefore, in order to compute the gradient at a given position and store it at that same position, we take into account only its neighbors (P(i+1)-P(i-1)).

Comment: Regarding the Dirac function: in fact, what you are using here is a **2D Dirac comb** (*i.e.* a sum of shifted Dirac functions). They are shifted by +/-1 and weighted by +/-1 or +/-2.

Comment: I get it. b[0, 0] are the surrounding pixels so they have value 1. the  center pixel is b[1, 1] so its value is 0. This is great. Thanks.

Comment: ...Maybe I don't get it. The only time b[x,y] will be b[0,0] is when we are on the center pixel. Therefore only the center pixel will get counted.

Comment: Dirac function is defined as being equal to infinite in 0 and equal to 0 anywhere else.
The **discrete** version of Dirac function is defined as equal to 1 in 0 and equal to 0 anywhere else. 
The (horizontal) Sobel kernel is defined as a weighted sum of **shifted** Dirac functions: equal to 1 in (-1,1) and (1,1), to 2 in (0,1), to -1 in (-1,-1) and (1,-1) and to -2 in (0,-1). Therefore, only neighbor rows (columns) are considered.

The filtering is a convolution of the image with your kernel: 

dx(i,j)=-1*im(i-1,j-1) + 1*im(i-1,j+1) – 2*im(i,j-1) + 2*im(i,j+1) – 1*im(i+1,j-1) + 1*im(i+1,j+1)